# PHP/SQL Testing Environment

Tags: php, sql, apache, phpmyadmin, mamp

Hey, a beginner's question here....
In order to learn PHP and SQl I have set up a Localhost Server on my computer running Apache and phpmyadmin, using MAMP.

In the course of testing, I have found that through the backend phpmyadmin interface I can modify the db as I please without any trouble. However, when I try to query the db through php scripts, no changes seem to be committed.

I say this because it seems that I am able to open a connection to phpmyadmin, evident by the error messages I receive when trying to pass a malformed query.

When I run these scripts, and then check the backend, I see no changes even though I received no errors.

My best guess would be php is incorrect. So here is what I am using.

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "roo", "root");
if(!$connect){
    die('COULD NOT CONNECT! HURS WHY : ' . mysql_error());
    }
echo "Connection Success";

mysql_select_db("Geodb", $connect);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO countries (country_code, country_name)
VALUES ('uk', 'United Kingdom')");

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

I suspect that this has been a problem because i am a beginner, but I have tried solving it and searched for an answer... So I hope you won't mind helping me out haha.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that an error is being thrown, but not displayed due to your `display_errors` php.ini setting. As such, I'd recommend checking your error logs.

Additionally, as this isn't a production environment (and hence it's OK to show errors) you'll probably want to change your display_errors setting to on (`display_errors = On`) and your error_reporting level to...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
```

or, better still...

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

...within your php.ini file.

By doing this, you'll be informed of all the errors, warnings and notices that are occurring.

Comment: Oh thanks for that. I probably would never have found it. I figured out my problem by the way... For some odd reason my user privileges were not configured correctly. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: @Pete No problem - hope it all goes well. (Stack Overflow is a great resource if you get stuck.) :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be happening when you select the database. What you can do is:

```
if(!mysql_select_db("Geodb", $connect))
  die ("Couldn't find the db".mysql_error());
```

Comment: I discovered my problem was that my user privileges were not configured properly. Thanks for the help though!